# didSelectRowAtIndex freezes the Apple Watch app

Tags: swift, tableview, watchkit, apple-watch, didselectrowatindexpath

In my WatchKit app, I have a Table View and I'm trying to execute two different methods by pressing two different rows (last and the one before it) in the table.

The code below runs `method1`, but never executes `method2` even though `tableView.numberOfRows` is correct. Instead of executing the method2, the app loads endlessly and freezes.

What could possibly be wrong with the code?

```
override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
    if table==tableView && rowIndex==tableView.numberOfRows-2 {
        print("Its up")
        print(tableView.numberOfRows)
        method1()
    } else if table==tableView && rowIndex==tableView.numberOfRows-1 {
        print("It's down")
        print(tableView.numberOfRows)
        method2()
    } else {
        print("Nothing is happening")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it going into the second blockand printing It's down.. if ao then show whats happening in method2

Comment: I would either attach with the debugger to see or look at the Devices window log for the phone, it sounds like it crashes.

Comment: @ArunGupta the problem is - it never executes the method2, it just freezes even before that point. checked with the debugger.

Comment: Is there any reason you are checking for tableView and tableView.numberOfRows in condition which can be easily be replaced by the datasource or array for displaying. You can replace the conditions like list.count -2 for first if and list.count - 1 for second if where list is your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if table=tableView && rowIndex==tableView.numberOfRows-2 {
```

maybe first equal should be ==

Comment: actually it already is ==, i misspelled the code. that's not the issue.

Comment: post method 1 and numofrows methed

Comment: let's assume that method1 just prints out a string - numberOfRows represents the quantity of rows in a tableView, it's not a method by itself